# When uploading a very large file in PHP, how much RAM is required on the server?

Tags: php

I read  http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size.

memory_limit must > post_max_size . Then if  user upload a file 500MB then how much total RAM use ?

does it use >500MB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, memory_limit need not be greater than post_max_size.

PHP has different POST readers and handlers depending on the content type of the request. In case of "multipart/form-data" (what is used for sending files), [`rfc1867_post_handler`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?revision=302387&view=markup#l755) acts as a mixed reader/handler. It populates both `$_POST` and `$_FILES`. What goes into `$_POST` counts towards the memory limit, what goes into `$_FILES` also counts.

However, `$_FILES` has just meta-data about the files, not the files themselves. Those are just written into the disk and hence don't count towards the memory limit.

Comment: *"No, memory_limit need not be greater than post_max_size."* The docs he linked suggest that it *should* be, though: *"Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger than `post_max_size`."* Fantastic link to source, though!

Comment: Basically what you're saying, then, is that files posted in the normal way are processed by that handler, which writes the files to disk. But that code seems to be working from a *memory buffer*, which would suggest that prior to the handler writing them to disk, the file data is in memory (and thus presumably subject to the memory limit). I hope I'm wrong about that, but it's how a survey of the code seems to read.

Comment: @t-j-crowder I'm not exactly sure. My understanding is that if it's a normal form variable, it's read in all to memory. But if it's a file, it's written to the disk in a temp file. Check out [Line 903](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?revision=302387&view=markup#l903) and [Line 1068](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/main/rfc1867.c?revision=302387&view=markup#l1068)

Comment: A file is buffered in phsycail memory between swapping to disk.